# Share Log Analytics reports

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I'm creating some `Log Analytics` to collect data from `Event Hub` and `Application Insights`.

Can `Log Analytics` reports be viewed by users outside of Azure? For example, can I give to my client a dashboard or report? If not what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can Log Analytics reports be viewed by users outside of Azure?

In short, **Yes**.

To create a dashboard, select the **New dashboard** button next to the current dashboard's name.
[image]
When you create a dashboard, it is private by default, which means you are the only person who can see it. To make it visible to others, use the **Share** button that appears alongside the other dashboard commands.
[image]

Then go to the Log Analytics portal, enter the **query Statement** to return record and display in a visual chart.

Finally, pin this to the shared dashboard created earlier by selecting **Pin chart to your Azure dashboard** button from the middle-right corner of the page.

For more details, you could refer to this article about how to [share dashboards of Log Analytic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-logs-dashboards)s data.

To share a dashboard and be able to add others to be able to share it **must be an Owner on the subscription level**.

Once you have shared a dashboard, use the **Unshare** option to change permissions on that dashboard. Clicking on Unshare brings up a new view on the right side where you can now choose **Manage users**.

[image]

Summary: To effectively share and control who has access to your shared dashboard you need owner rights on the subscription. When you want to change who can see your shared dashboard use the `Unshare` option. Finally, you need at least reader rights to the OMS workspace, **contributor rights in Azure to Log Analytics**, and **reader access to the dashboards** resource group to view the various objects on your shared dashboard.

Please refer to this [article](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/cfuller/archive/2018/02/05/delving-deeper-into-sharing-azure-dashboards/).